# How to allow flex item images to shrink and not go off the page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There are icons below and when the screen shrinks these icons overflow off the page. I've tried setting mid-width 100% and other techniques but nothing works. How can I allow these flex item images to shrink and not go off the page?

```css
.container3 {
  background-color: #e0dfdf;
}

.field2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Carnas-Light;
  color: #008ad1!important;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 140px;
  padding-left: 140px;
}

.icons {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container3">
  <h2 class="field2">A few of our customers that have already improved their business with WorkWave</h2>
  <div class="icons">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/dBwHRS/customers_relayfoods.png" alt="customers_relayfoods" border="0">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/dBwHRS/customers_relayfoods.png" alt="customers_relayfoods" border="0">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/dBwHRS/customers_relayfoods.png" alt="customers_relayfoods" border="0">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/dBwHRS/customers_relayfoods.png" alt="customers_relayfoods" border="0">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/dBwHRS/customers_relayfoods.png" alt="customers_relayfoods" border="0">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/dBwHRS/customers_relayfoods.png" alt="customers_relayfoods" border="0">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add absolute path for image or repalce them with placeholder ?

Comment: sorry i realized the images themselves were the reason for the discrepancy, but i'm still having trouble getting them to stay on the page.

Comment: For `.icons` set `flex-wrap: wrap`. The default is no wrap, which is why they are all in one row

Comment: perfect! thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div class="container3">
      <h2 class="field2">A few of our customers that have already improved their business with WorkWave</h2>
      <div class="icons">
        <div>
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/dBwHRS/customers_relayfoods.png" alt="customers_relayfoods" border="0">
        </div>
        <div>
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/dBwHRS/customers_relayfoods.png" alt="customers_relayfoods" border="0">
        </div>
        <div>
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/dBwHRS/customers_relayfoods.png" alt="customers_relayfoods" border="0">
        </div>
        <div>
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/dBwHRS/customers_relayfoods.png" alt="customers_relayfoods" border="0">
        </div>
        <div>
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/dBwHRS/customers_relayfoods.png" alt="customers_relayfoods" border="0">
        </div>
        <div>
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/dBwHRS/customers_relayfoods.png" alt="customers_relayfoods" border="0">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



.container3 {
  background-color: #e0dfdf;
}

.field2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Carnas-Light;
  color: #008ad1!important;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 140px;
  padding-left: 140px;
}

.icons {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
}
.icons img {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Just wrap all img tags in a div and add 100% width to img.